# Neumann problem, stuck on a boundary condition.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am stuck on a problem that I am trying for exam practice and I would very much appreciate a hint to help me out, here is the section where I am stuck:

> A solution is sought to the Neumann problem for $\nabla^2 u = 0$ in the half plane $z > 0$:
>   $u = O(|x|^{−a}),
> \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}
> = O(|x|^{−a−1}) ~~ \mathrm{as} ~~  |x| → ∞,~~ \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} ~
> = p(x, y) ~ on ~ z = 0,
> \mathrm{where}~ a > 0$. It is assumed that
>   $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> p(x, y) dx dy = 0$. Explain why this condition is
>   necessary.

My feeling is that this is to do with Green's third identity and that we need the normal derivative in the $x-y$ plane to be integrable in order to find out solution with a Green's function, am I correct?

---

EDIT:
the divergence theorem sorts this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\int\int u_z$. Then $f_z=\int\int u_{zz} =\int\int (-u_{xx}-u_{yy})$. Consider this quantity and also $\lim _{z\to\infty} f(z)$. That should give you the result you want.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really understand how this will give me what I need. Can you go a little further please? There may well be something fundamental that I a missing here.

Comment: I've got it now. thank you.